# How to avoid reading the graph for each request in Tensorflow

Tags: python, flask, tensorflow, flask-restful

I have a Tensorflow python class that is called from a REST endpoint and passed in a URL for an image. Each time a new request is initiated, it calls the `create_graph` method which reads a local `.pb` file. This file does not change from request to request. So, I feel it is not a good use of resources and time to read this file at each request.

The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import urllib2

class MyTensorflow:

  def __init__(self, url):
     self.imageUrl = imageUrl

  def create_graph(self):
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/path/to/model.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

   def run_inference_on_image(self):
     image_string = urllib2.urlopen(self.imageUrl).read()
     with tf.Session() as sess:
       ...
       ...
       return a_text_value
```

The above code is called from `flask_restful` like this:

```
c = my_tensorflow.MyTensorflow(args['url'])
    c.create_graph()
    returned = c.run_inference_on_image()
```

**Question**

Is there any way to only call `create_graph` at the first request and then not call it until the service is restarted?

Comment: `before_first_request(f)`
Registers a function to be run before the first request to this instance of the application. What about it?

Answer (score 0):

For serving: Create the session only once per process. You can call Session.run() many times.